# Cannot open file unless in administrator mode

Tags: python, file, input, path

I wrote a python program that takes CSV file as input and saves all its lines as list (there is one value in each line so eventually I save a list of strings).
when I run the program from the CMD in the folder of the program\venv\scripts It is not working but it is working from Pycharm when I press "run".
The code of the function is:

```
def __read_from_csv_file(self):
    if pathlib.Path(self.input_file_path).exists():
        try:
            with open(self.input_file_path, 'r', newline='') as csv_file:
                csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
                for line in csv_reader:
                    # Each line is a list so I take the line[0] to extract the key itself from the first cell
                    # of the line.
                    self.strings_to_check.append(line[0])
        except Exception as e:
            print('CryptoDetect::__read_from_csv_file::Exception caught: ' + "There was an error while trying "
                                                                             "the file: " +
                  self.input_file_path)
            print('The error is ' + e)
    else:
        raise Exception('CryptoDetect::__read_from_csv_file::Exception caught: ' + "The argument of input file is "
                                                                                   "not a valid path, either the "
                                                                                   "file not exist or the program "
                                                                                   "does not has permission to "
                                                                                   "open or read it.")
```

The problem is with the first line of the function, the if result is false.
Can someone please help me to understand why this is happening and how to fix it?
Thank you.

Comment: Can you show the code you use? Also, is the error really `""`, an empty string? Maybe you accidentally open the file for both reading and writing instead of opening it read-only, which is then denied because you don't have write access to that file as non-administrator?

Comment: no its not the error I accidentally did not paste the error. I will edit it now and add the code.

Comment: @CherryDT I changed it. Hope the problem is more clear now. Thank you.